# lucene ParseException when the query is too long

Tags: lucene, parseexception

org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(String arg0) throws ParseException when the String arg0 is too long, is there any idea on how to avoid this problem?

Comment: You don't happen to have a stack trace available? How long queries are we talking about?

Comment: the query is around 12000 characters and here's the log:

Comment: on second thought the log wouldn't really matter because it's specific, but the problem is obvious i am using org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse and the string looks somewhat like this: ...OR ID:(61) OR ID:(60) OR ID:(58) OR ID:(54) OR ID:(45) OR ID:(43)) AND (cs_contents:(gaz) OR cs_docs:(gaz))) +DBName:dPortal +TableName:CSBLOG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the issue is length, then the underlying issue is a TooManyClauses exception, I'm guessing.

You can deal with this directly by increasing the max clauses, by calling [`BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html#setMaxClauseCount%28int%29).

There a good chance that's just treating the symptom, though.  This typically indicates, that you can expect poor performance, due to having such broad queries.  You might consider trying to make use of `Filter`s for some part of the query, which may solve the issue and improve performance, or otherwise improving how you query the index.